# How to selected all the installed kernels and its variants via bash

Tags: bash, kernel, scripts

I would like to selected all the installed kernels, including its headers, modules, extras, hwe and architecture, but excluding the current one. So far I have this, but it's not working well:

```
# Search for all the  kernels
CURRENT$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
PART01="linux-(generic|image|headers|modules|modules-extra)"
PART02="linux-(generic|image|headers|modules|modules-extra)-(hwe|i386|amd64)"
PART03="linux-(image|headers|moduels|modules-extra)-(generic)-(hwe|i386|amd64)"
OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $PART01 |grep -E $PART02 |grep -vE $PART03|grep -v $CURRENT)
```

I'm targeting Ubuntu 18.04 up

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, does this answer help? https://askubuntu.com/a/4284/656190

Comment: Thanks..but it doesn't catch the `-modules`

Comment: Since when the old kernels are deleted and system figures which modules are no longer useful, doesn't it? `sudo apt autoremove`